# the open source software has a Installation file，Ｉ changed it,when I reinstall the software,I encounter some problems

Tags: svn

I am using ubuntu16.04 system,python2.7.I have installed a open source software package successfully, the package has a master-install.py to be used to install the software,now I changed some content of the software,As the software has a lot of things to be installed such as "GSL,FFTW"and I just want reinstall the content I changed,so I changed the master-install.py,remove the content used to install "FFTW" and so on,when I try to run  it ,it displayed:
`svn: E155007: '/home/fanhm/xx is not a working copy`,who can hlep me,thank you.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have completed the question.

Comment: yes,it missed the question,the question is：svn: E155007: '/home/fanhm/xxx' is not a working copy